# Is this authentication with Passport secure by design?

Tags: node.js, security, authentication, https, passport.js

I'm new to Node, Passport and authentication in web development in general

I followed [this tutorial for setting up **local** authentication using the Passport module](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local).

I was hoping an experienced developer could comment on the security of the design being taught there.

More specifically,

1) When the author does a POST for sending credentials, shouldn't he be doing it over HTTPS? When is it necessary to use HTTPS so that others aren't sniffing your information? How could the design be changed to POST using HTTPS?

2) I can't follow how session is being kept track of. Does passport abstract all of the session work? If so, are they using cookies? Are the cookies plaintext? Does the user get a token back in a cookie? Is that how isLoggedIn() works?

3) Is he getting any protection from content injection for free? I don't see any code to try and escape dangerous characters or anything.

Anyway, how hacker safe is this design?

Comment: you are over thinking it, if SSL is used then its considered a safe request between your app and authentication provider. Session are like classic session, an id in cookie its the most common .. What do you mean "protection from content injection for free" ? the auth provider handles invalid requests and stuff .. sanitizing and validating a login using something like twitter, won't make a difference..Om the other side, if you application is compromised and dangerous code run, someone could achieve pretty much anything with a few http requests, but thats not the issue here.

Comment: I don't think the login is going over SSL in the tutorial above. By content injection I mean adding dangerous script in credentials for example.

Comment: in any of the cases you mention in comment above, the auth provider will return a failure redirect or possibly an error, it just won't allow anything and fail. You don't need to worry about XSS.